# Only one of the filters works?

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

My advanced filter is working perfectly, except for the fact that if the first filter is empty, none of the other filters work...

My first filter is Year, and if I leave it blank to just look for a country, it simply clears all the data.

(it won't let me upload a picture cuz its too many mb)
But basically it looks like this:

Filters: Year, Country, Era

If I input a year, it shows the right data including the right data for country and era, but if I leave year blank, and input Country and/or Era, no data shows.

I used a recording macro to create the advanced filter in VBA.

My code:

```
Sheet7.Range("B4").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=XlFilterCopy, _
Criteria Range:=Range("K2:N3"), CopyToRange:=("B8:I8"), Unique:=False
```

Comment: Code: Sheet7.Range("B4").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=x1FilterCopy, _ CriteriaRange:=Range("K2:N3"), CopyToRange:=Range("B8:I8"), Unique:=False

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code to your question. Show an example of your data (eg screenshot) and provide the relevant code part or better a [mcve]. Code in comments is not helpful. Also include what you expect vs what your code actually did. Because *"did not work"* is meaningless and no useful error description.

Comment: Note you have a typo in your code: `=X1FilterCopy` must be `=xlFilterCopy` after the `X` there is a lower case `L` not a one `1`! • Also there is no space in  `Criteria Range:=` it must be `CriteriaRange:=` • See the documentation [Range.AdvancedFilter method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.advancedfilter) • I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit` to avoid such typos: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure you clear the area where you want to paste into *before* you filter.
- Make sure your range addresses fit *exactly* the data
- `CopyToRange:=("B8:I8")` is no valid range it must be `CopyToRange:=Range("B8:I8")`

The following will work as expected on the example shown below:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ApplyAdvancedFilter()

    Range("B4").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range("K2:M3"), CopyToRange:=Range("B12"), Unique:=False

End Sub
```

[image]

For more information have a look at …

- … the documentation: [Range.AdvancedFilter method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.advancedfilter)
- … this tutorial: [Easy Excel - Advanced Filter](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/advanced-filter.html)